# Not clear how to vectorize this function to get rid of fsurf warning in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, plot, vectorization

To use `fsurf`, one needs to properly vectorize the function under consideration, which means to use element-wise operations, i.e. array operations.

As an example, this function is properly vectorized:

`f = x.^2 -2 * x .* y + 4 * y.^2`

Now, my question is: how would you vectorize **this** function (a,b,c,d,e are just constants)?

`f = a + [b, c]*[x - d; y - e]`

In such a case, I cannot use an element-wise multiplication (i.e., `.*`), as I need that operation to return a scalar, not a matrix, so using `*` is correct.

While the plot returned by `fsurf` is definitely correct, I get this warning message:

*Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs. To improve performance, properly vectorize your function to return an output with the same size and shape as the input arguments.*

How would you proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix operation within your formula is difficult to vectorize. Grab pen and paper and perform the matrix multiplication:

```
f = a - b.*(d - x) - c.*(e - y)
```

Only multiplications with a scalar left, easy to vectorize.

Comment: Thank you! By doing that, I actually do not need `.*`.
This is already fine for `fsurf`: `a + b*(x - d) + c*(y - e)`

Comment: You are right, the `.*` would only be required if you ended up with something like `x*y`. Here it does not matter.